# Haskell tree size

Tags: haskell, tree

Still a haskell noob here!

I am trying to get the size of a tree?

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)

size :: Tree a -> Int
size empty = 0
size (Leaf n)    = 1
size (Node x z) = size x + size z + 1
```

If I call the function with

```
size (Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3)) (Leaf 2))
```

All I get is 0. Is the code correct and I am just not calling it correctly?

BTW, I have seen lots of examples with Empty instead of empty, but this causes an error when compiling. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have an overlapping pattern match in your `size` function. The line `size empty` will be always pattern matched resulting in the value of `0` always. Your `size` function should be like this:

```
size :: Tree a -> Int
size (Leaf n)    = 1
size (Node x z) = size x + size z + 1
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> size (Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3)) (Leaf 2))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is problematic:

```
size empty = 0
```

`empty` is not a constructor, so it matches anything, and immediately returns 0, making your function equivalent to `const 0`.

Because there is *no way to make an empty tree with your definition*, it's pointless adding such a line.

If you did want to make an Empty tree possible, you'd have to change your definitions a bit:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

size Empty        = 0
size (Node _ a b) = 1 + size a + size b
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the problem. How do I get Empty to work? import some thing perhaps?

Comment: @user3633383 Have a look at your tree datatype. Is it even possible to have an empty tree by your definition?